# Добавление столбцов, через миграции

Tags: php, laravel

было так

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('images', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('image');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Добавил поля и получилось так

```
     public function up()
{
    Schema::create('images', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('image');
        $table->string('desciption');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->nullableTimestamps();

    });
}
```

Если прописать в консоле php artisan migrate

То пишет Nothing to migrate.

Как быть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Добавление столбцов, через миграции

Нужно создать новый файл со звучным названием того, что вы добавляете.

Например:

*add_desciption_to_images.php*

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('images', function($table) {
        $table->string('desciption');
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::table('images', function($table) {
        $table->dropColumn('desciption');
    });
}
```

Команда для artisan:

```
php artisan make:migration add_desciption_to_images
```

Comment: Я это сделал и выводит ошибку, Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42S21]: Column already exists: 1060 Duplicate column name 'created_at' (SQL: alter table `images` add `desciption` varchar(255) not null, add `created_at` timestamp null, add `updated_at` timestamp null)

Comment: @DivMan вы успели сделать, код из моего примера? Какая у вас версия Laravel?

Comment: Версия 5.6 Я такой же способ пробовал

Comment: @DivMan а зачем вы добавляете `$table->nullableTimestamps();`? Вы же уже создали `created_at`, `updated_at`. Эта функция вызывает `$table->timestamps();`

Comment: Спасибо, ваш код работает, я вроде бы так же делал, но почему-то не работало

Comment: @DivMan не за что. =)

Comment: Это я добавил, что бы посмотреть, когда создалась новость, а то в created_at ничего не записывается